# yq append to a very nested yaml

Tags: command-line, command, yq

I have this yaml :

```
routes:
  T_NAME:
    paths:
      T_PATH:
        - allowed_methods:
          - GET
          matching_policy: prefix
          auth:
            jwt:
              required: true
              scopes:
                allOf:
                  - scope1
```

I would like to append elements in allOf

```
for i in ${nemo[@]}; do
  yq ".routes.T_NAME.paths.T_PATH.allowed_methods.auth.jwt.scopes.allOf += \"${i}\"" note.yaml
done
```

This is not working, any idea please

Comment: Are you using kislyuk/yq or mikefarah/yq? (See the `yq` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info))

Comment: i am usingmikefarah/yq

Answer (score 1):

With [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), you can pass the original input array i.e. `nemo` as an argument list and receive it as a string input in `yq`'s context and then split it on a single whitespace, to obtain the list of elements.

```bash
nemo=(a b c) # Sample input
myenv="${nemo[*]}" yq '.routes.T_NAME.paths.T_PATH[0].auth.jwt.scopes.allOf += ( strenv(myenv) | split(" ")  )' yaml
```

produces the desired output as expected.

```yaml
routes:
  T_NAME:
    paths:
      T_PATH:
        - allowed_methods:
            - GET
          matching_policy: prefix
          auth:
            jwt:
              required: true
              scopes:
                allOf:
                  - scope1
                  - a
                  - b
                  - c
```

Uses the [split](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/string-operators#split-strings) and [strenv](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/env-variable-operators#read-numeric-environment-variable-as-a-string) methods. Tested on v4.32.2